# Speeding up CNN training

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks

So I built a CNN without any scientific libraries like [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) or [Keras](https://keras.io/) (only [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/)). It is taking a huge amount of time to train. What are some of the tricks and tips followed by people to speed up training of a CNN? (I am not talking about division of jobs into different processors but subtle redundant codes i.e. giving pre-calculated results which is not visible to common programmers).

Comment: This is rather hard to answer without knowing more details... Have you tried profiling it to see where the bottlenecks are? Is it floating-point arithmetic? Data I/O?

Comment: @OliverMason I agree details are not there but there must be some standard checks performed by programmers...this is more of a general open ended question for future references rather than code specific

Comment: @OliverMason what do you mean by profiling? (I am not conversant with programming terminology)

Comment: Measure where the time is being spent within the program. Then you can focus on those parts, rather than spend lots of time speeding up something that is fast anyway.

Comment: Why are you even caring about the speed of a hand-rolled, non-accelerated CNN implementation? You only build those to understand what's happening. The goal in insight, not performance.

Comment: @MSalters in this specific scenario it is...but i have to tackle a problem in the future which demands self made code...also your view is correct, but if i want to gain intuition then i cannot let the network train for such a long time..i need quick action->cause

Comment: @DuttaA: A simple CNN for MNIST digits will do for insight. As for the "a problem that demands self-made code"... - problems don't demand that. You may have non-technical issues here, but there are other sites for that sort of issues (depending on where that mistaken demand is coming from)

Comment: @MSalters i do not think you are correct..not all devices can support tensorflow or keras now is it? Even older models with older GPU's do not support porcessor sharing properties of tensorflow...so it is bad to jump to conclusions...I could have posted this first on DS.SE (I eventually did) but this site has a problem of user growth and good questions so I present more general problems here

Comment: @DuttaA: CUDA 9.2 requires Kepler or newer. That's for instance a GT 710, available for € 33,17 including VAT. But Tensorflow doesn't require a GPU at all. As for multi-processor? Are we still talking about MNIST or similar-sized problems? I mean, my company has spent a very significant amount of money collecting our dataset, it's far larger than MNIST, and yet we still don't _need_ multiple GPU's.

Answer (score 1):

[Ref-some standard checks performed by programmers]

**[Speeding up Convolutional Neural Networks with Low Rank Expansions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.3866.pdf)**

From the abstract:

> The focus of this paper is speeding up the evaluation of convolutional neural networks. While delivering impressive results across a range of computer vision and machine learning tasks, these networks are computationally demanding, limiting their deployability.
>
> Convolutional layers generally consume the bulk of the processing time, and so in this work we present two simple schemes for drastically speeding up these layers. This is achieved by exploiting cross-channel or filter redundancy to construct a low rank basis of filters that are rank-1 in the spatial domain.
>
> Our methods are architecture agnostic, and can be easily applied to existing CPU and GPU convolutional frameworks for tuneable speedup performance. We demonstrate this with a real world network designed for scene text character recognition, showing a possible 2.5x speedup with no loss in accuracy, and 4.5x speedup with less than 1% drop in accuracy, still achieving state-of-the-art on standard benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations:

- Try deleting some variables that will no longer be used during run-time
- Use more efficient data structure
- Get your hands on some optimized library for your hardware, e.g. if you are using Intel processors use the Intel distribution of python
- Pay careful attention to your data types and try to trim them as much as possible